# AngularJs Date filter and 1970-01-01 returns 1969-12-31?

Tags: angularjs, timezone, filtering

I'm not quite sure how to set the timezone in angularjs for the date filter, which converts 1970-01-01 to 1969-12-31. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788691/java-simpledateformat-and-19700101-conversion-problem), which explains the same problem in Java, but not sure how to approach it in AngularJs - any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The JavaScript date is  based on a time value that is milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC. A day holds 86,400,000 milliseconds. The JavaScript Date object range is -100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days relative to 01 January, 1970 UTC.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

JavaScript `Date` type does not have timezone support* you need to use either `ISO 8601` format or send `timestamp` in UTC.

You can also use a library like [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) or [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks - this suggestion is the closest to the one I've used so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for participating.
After quite a bit of time trying to find an easy way to resolve the problem I've found the solution - by simply using Date and one of it's methods:

```
new Date(date).toISOString();
```

That does the job and is super short :)

Answer (score 1):

The angular [developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) says this about timezones:

> The Angular datetime filter uses the time zone settings of the browser. The same application will show different time information depending on the time zone settings of the computer that the application is running on. Neither JavaScript nor Angular currently supports displaying the date with a timezone specified by the developer.

You can make your own filter to use a specific timezone.  Here is a simple one using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to parse 19700101 with the GMT timezone:

```
app.filter('GMT', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return moment(input + ' +0000', "YYYYMMDD").format('MMM DD, YYYY');
  };
});
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/l5zd9Z1tli2NLmgPTWhJ